# How to get an object member value after it is defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, settimeout

I have an object in javascript:

```
var a = {
    n1: 1,
    n2: 2
}
```

I want to get the value of `a.n3`, but `n3` will be added to the object at a later time.

How to get the value of `n3` without using any loops and causing any error?

**EDIT**

The object `a` is sort of a container where different scripts from different scopes are adding variables to asynchronously (I am using requireJS to maintain the scripts).

One of my scripts `init.js` expects to get the property `n3` from the object, but the property `n3` is added to the object by a different script `swatchRenderer.js`, which, unfortunately, is being called **after** `init.js`. Hence the `init.js` script is not getting the value `n3`.

So is there any way to stall fetching of the value in `init.js`.

**NOTE**: I cannot change the order in which the scripts are loaded.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you're trying to do. Can you post more of your code so we have a sense of what you're really aiming to accomplish? (can you just wait until the object gets mutated to check the property?)

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Comment: You want to get the value of a property of an object before the property is added and the value is set. Can you explain what that means to people Who aren't Time Lords?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have edited the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say your script is loaded first. What you could do it keep fetching the value every `x` seconds, until the value is found.

**Example**

```
var fetchN3 = function () {
    if (obj.n3 === undefined){
        return setTimeout(function() {
            fetchN3();
        }, 500);
    }
    console.log("Found N3!!!", obj.n3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `a.n3` will be `undefined` if it does not exist in the object `a`. Thus you can use a `if` condition to prevent errors.

```js
var a = {
    n1: 1,
    n2: 2
}

if(a.n3){
  console.log('value found first');
}
a.n3 = 10;
if(a.n3){
  console.log('value found second');
}
```

But lets say that the `n3` is a `boolean` value then this `if` condition will not work so the best way could be to check the type `undefined` like,

```js
var a = {
    n1: 1,
    n2: 2
}

if(typeof a.n3 !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('value found first');
}
a.n3 = false;
if(typeof a.n3 !== 'undefined'){
  console.log('value found second');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var value = a.n3;
```

if value is undefined, then n3 is not defined yet, if it is defined, then you get it is value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function given the new value of `n3` when it gets changed, one option is using a getter/setter:

```js
const a = {
  n1: 1,
  n2: 2,
  get n3() {
    return this._n3;
  },
  set n3(val) {
    this._n3 = val;
    console.log('saw change, new val: ' + val);
  },
};
console.log('start');
a.n3 = 'foo';
console.log('end');
```

But that's not something to rely on usually - it would be better to trigger something external when the object gets changed.

More details/examples on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Comment: You can include a reference to this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters where is an example almost like yours but with more documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use This function of JavaScript (This is example only)

```js
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}
var obj = {
 n1: 2,
 n2: 3
}
async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  if (obj.n3) {
    console.log("obj.n3 found");
     //Here do your task
     return;
  }else {
   asyncCall();
  }
  // expected output: "resolved"
}

asyncCall();
```

Comment: I can not use Promise as it is not supported by some of the browsers. Any other solutions?